# I'm getting a error when adding on a list then getting that list in a for loop in python

Tags: python

So yea im making a partical physics simulation and im using pygame, so im using lists to store the x and y variables for each partical, also im using list to store the actual particals themselfs. so i want to create an create fuction that can create many particals at one, so what i was doing was adding a new number to the x and y list and then geting the index of the length and use that as the index to get that number. here is the code...

```py
import pygame
import math
import random


pygame.display.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))

currentXindex = 0
currentYindex = 0

X = [400, 300]
Y = [300, 400]

VelX = [0]
VelY = [0]





while True:
  
  screen.fill((0,0,0))
  
  Particals = []
  
  pygame.display.flip()
  
  for x in range(0, 10):
    X.append(random.randint(300, 500))
    Y.append(random.randint(300, 500))
    Particals.append(pygame.draw.circle(screen, (255, 255, 255), (X[len(X)], Y[len(Y)]), 50)
```

so after that i get an error saying "unexpected EOF while parsing" can anyone help me with this...

Answer (score 0):

Index of an array starts with 0, so if you want to get the last element of an array, you should use "len(X) - 1" as index instead.
Actually, you can use X[-1] to get the last element of an array in Python.

Comment: thanks mekal i tried that and it does not work it says that it is out of index.

Comment: @BigFatBadCoder You have two typos in you code:
1. "unexpected EOF while parsing", because you didn't colse the parenthesis in last line.
2. "out of index", because you use len(X) as index, instead you should use len(x) or directly -1.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't close a parenthesis.

```
        Particals.append(pygame.draw.circle(screen, (255, 255, 255), (X[len(X)], Y[len(Y)]), 50))
```